# Your server administrator has limited the number of items you can open simultaneously

Tags: exchange-2007, outlook-2007, synchronization, calendar

I receive the following sync error in Outlook 2007 SP2:

> Your server administrator has limited
>   the number of items you can open
>   simultaneously. Try closing messages
>   you have opened or removing
>   attachments and images from unsent
>   messages you are composing.

It is stopping me updating another user's calendar, which is open within my Outlook.  Change are simply not syncing, either way.

Is there a fix for this, e.g. increasing the number of permitted connections on the Exchange Server?  We are using Exchange Server 2007 on a domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually caused by creating too many RPC connections to Exchange. Do you have alot of notifications, or reminders open, or not dismissed, as these can create an RPC connection each.

You can disable the session limit by changing the following registry key on the server:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSExchangeIS\ParametersSystem\Disable Session Limit
```

Set it to 1 to disable. However, you may want to find out the underlying cause as to why you are using up the connections, rather than disabling it, as too many connections will have a performance impact on your exchange server.

Comment: +1. This is definitely an UNUSUAL thing to check. I use outlook quite heavily (latest version always) and never had this issue pop up. And know nooone who hat. So, an investigation seems to be in order.

Answer (score 1):

I just faced the same problem and found out that it might be related to [Performance problems when you try to access folders in a secondary mailbox in Outlook 2010](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2297543).

Comment: Seems unlikely given that the OP was using Outlook 2007.  But anything's possible, I suppose.